# how to change data-value on div by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project that I need to change attribute of data-value by js language.

You can see the code here.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="ldBar auto no-percent label-center m-auto" id="tree"

    style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"

  >>>>>>data-value="50"<<<<<<

     data-type="fill" data-img="tree1.svg" data-fill="data:ldbar/res,bubble(#f00,#d00,100,1)"
     data-fill-background="#ddd"
      data-fill-background-extrude="0">
      <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-4.5 -4.5 109 109">
      </svg>
      <div class="ldBar-label"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As it seems data-value is set 50. By this I am just making image fill up to 50 per cent. But I want to change this value automatically. A Js code that makes it lets say 25. How can have this access to change this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple pure-js example for read and write data-attributes:

```js
var setDataAttribute = function() {
  var dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-container');
  var dataValue = parseInt(dataContainer.getAttribute('data-value'));
  dataContainer.setAttribute('data-value', dataValue + 1);
  dataContainer.innerHTML = dataValue + 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="data-container" data-value="25">25</div>
<button onclick="setDataAttribute()">increase data value</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [**`.data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get/set the attribute value:

```js
$('#tree').data('value', '25');
console.log($('#tree').data('value')); // 25
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="ldBar auto no-percent label-center m-auto" id="tree" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;" data-value="50"
   data-type="fill" data-img="tree1.svg" data-fill="data:ldbar/res,bubble(#f00,#d00,100,1)"
   data-fill-background="#ddd"
    data-fill-background-extrude="0">
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-4.5 -4.5 109 109">
    </svg>
    <div class="ldBar-label"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this works, but will not update the DOM. Whether that's important depends on how the value is read later on. If it's read using the getter of `data()`, then it will work. If not, then you'll need to use `attr()` to get/set it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if I use data one inside my another script, on console I am seeing the value I set. if I put attr() I am seeing the value is set already in div. But for both cases I cannot able to alter this value..